# Can't set url value for $_GET when linking to another page via <a> tag

Tags: php, sql

I have a login page that starts a session, sets a email and `session_id` value in to a `loggedin` database table. When login successful, it goes to

```
dashboard.php?sesid="session_id"
```

Now when I am on the dashboard page, I set `$userid` to that session id url value.

I have a link:

```
<a href="?sesid=".$userid."">Dashboard</a>
```

But when I click on it, the url just says

```
dashboard.php?sesid=
```

Why is the id not popping up?

Comment: Where does `$userid` come from? Is that link in an echo statement?

Comment: When I first login, there is a value for sesid.

I set $userid by declaring:

    `$userid=$_GET['sesid'];`

Comment: wait, should I echo $user id in <a> tag instead of ".$userid."

Comment: Make sure you have `session_start()` at top of page which sets the session.

Comment: Show us the full source code. <a href="?sesid=".$userid."">Dashboard</a> is invalid because of quotes and should be something like <a href=\"?sesid=".$userid."\">Dashboard</a> Also how do you get the value $userid you are trying to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link should look like this:

```
<a href="?sesid='<?php echo $userid; ?>'>Dashboard</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

Open your page source code and you will see the error.

You are missing the url quotes.

Replace

```
<a href="?sesid=".$userid."">
```

By

```
<a href=\"?sesid=".$userid."\">
```

Your html attribute quotes must be escaped using `\"`

Edit:

Or just don't concatenate the variable.
If you are using echo function with double quotes, you can just put the variable in the string, and it will be replaced automatically by its value.